# Does express next(err) have to have specific format?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, swagger

I have an express sub app using `http-errors` module. When I pass `new Forbidden()` to the `next()` callback it disappears into the ether and doesn't callback. If I pass `new Error()` or `{ message: 'Forbidden' }` it triggers the sub app error handler. Is this expected behaviour?

I've created my own Error objects and they all work. I see `http-errors` uses the `inherits` module, which works for me. Does the error handler check for anything on the error parameter?

I've used `http-errors` for years and not noticed this problem before.

```
const { Forbidden } = require('http-errors')
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

const subapp = express()

subapp.get((req, res, next) => {
  next(new Forbidden()) // doesn't work
  next(new Error()) // works
  next({ message: 'Forbidden' }) // works
})
subapp.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  // only called if new Error() or { message: 'Forbidden' }
})

app.use('/somepath', subapp)

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  // not called
})
```

## Edit:

I omitted that I was using swagger in the question above. Swagger was catching the error but not handling it appropriately; it was setting the correct headers but not sending a complete response. It was therefore missing my error middleware and passing on to the next non-error middleware.

```
// return response for http-errors error
subapp.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (res.headersSent) {
    return res.end()
  }
  next()
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the direct question, not it doesn't. We can test this with a simpler case shown in this code (tested).

```
const app = require('express')();

app.get('/test', (req, res, next) => {
    const nonErrObj = {
        hello: 'world'
    };

    return next(nonErrObj);
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Got an error');
    console.table(err);

    res.sendStatus(500);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on 3000');
});
```

By then running `curl localhost:3000/test` in another terminal we get the output:

```
listening on 3000
Got an error
┌─────────┬─────────┐
│ (index) │ Values  │
├─────────┼─────────┤
│  hello  │ 'world' │
└─────────┴─────────┘
```

This console.table is being output by our error handler, and the object we're passing to `next` is just a standard JS object. So the object passed to "next" can be anything and it will trigger the error handling code.

Now lets try and solve your issue. I have a hunch it's to do with your nested application which is good use of express but can get a bit confusing sometimes. I've created another test app using your code which shows the following. This code has only one global error handler.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const subapp = express();

// Create a top level route to test
app.get('/test', (req, res, next) => {
    const nonErrObj = {
        hello: 'world'
    };

    return next(nonErrObj);
});

// Create a sub express app to test
subapp.use('/test2', (req, res, next) => {
    const nonErrObj = {
        hello: 'world'
    };

    return next(nonErrObj);
});

// Mount the app, so we can now hit /subapp/test2
app.use('/subapp', subapp);

// A single global error handler for now
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Got an error');
    console.table(err);

    res.sendStatus(500);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on 3000');
});
```

If we now `curl localhost:3000/subapp/test2` and `curl localhost:3000/test` we get the same response. Our global error handler is called with no problems. Now lets try adding an error handler to the sub app to see what happens.

In this case I just added the following under the `/test2` route (not adding the full file for brevity.

```
subapp.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Sub app got error');
    console.table(err);

    res.sendStatus(500);
});
```

In this instance by doing the same thing, we can see that a request to `localhost:3000/subapp/test2` only calls the the sub app error handler. This shows that the errors are being handled properly.

**From the above we can see that there aren't any issues with random JS objects being passed through** (you can dig through the Express Router code and see this as well). The only reason I can see that the `http-errors` wouldn't be working properly would be if they are causing a conflict with the error handling code.

Looking at the [express router code](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/router/index.js#L176) we can see that it's picking up a few properties from the error object and acting based on that. I would check that your `http-errors` Forbidden error object isn't accidentally conflicting with one of these use cases. If that's the case, then I'd suggest finding a different error library.

**I'm assuming you're also using the npm [`http-errors`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-errors) library. If that's the case, it looks like you should be providing a message on error creation. You could be getting yourself into a situation where your program is hanging or erroring in some other way because you're not providing a message.**

Comment: Thanks for your very thorough answer. It turns out I forgot to mention that I'm using Swagger! Swagger accepts the error, sets the headers but doesn't send the response. So it gets passed onto the next "normal" middleware - hence not trigging my error middleware.